# Generate and Download a PDF within a shiny app. Error File not on site

Tags: pdf, download, pdf-generation, shinyapps

My primary goal is for users to download the PDF certificate that is produced when meet a passing score of 80% or more. Below I've share a reproduceable example of my code and the certificate made from a Rmd in which I have commented out the figures since I am not sure how to upload them. The app is published on shiny io. The error produced is "File is not available on site" by the browser but the PDF appears on my files tab which is not where I would like it produced, I need users to be able to take the exam and have them be able to download the PDF when the download button appears. Also, if anyone has any suggestions on how to reference the final score onto the PDF, since it's inside an observe event and my understanding is that the downloadHandler must be placed outside of an observe event. I've commented out the score part of the PDF at the moment. Any suggestions will be appreciated. But again my main concern is to have users to be able to download the PDF from their browser as shown on here, https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-downloadhandler-and-r-studio-export-as-pdf-cairo-pdf/12881/5 , posted by marsnone (last post).
**Rmd**

```
---
title: "Certificate"
output: pdf_document
classoption: landscape
header-includes:
  - \pagenumbering{gobble}
---
\begin{center}
<!-- \includegraphics[height=4cm]{fig1.png} -->
\hfill
<!-- \includegraphics[height=4cm]{fig2.jpg} \\ -->
\bigskip
\Huge\bf Certificate of Accomplishment \par
\bigskip
\Huge <<FIRSTNAME>> <<LASTNAME>> \par
\bigskip
\Large has successfully completed the exam over \par
{\it Colors \par}
\Large with a score of <<SCORE>>\% \par
\bigskip
\Huge Congratulations!\par
\end{center}
```

**Code**

```
# Load libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(shinyjs)
library(readr)

# TEST DATA
Knowledge <- 1
Comprehension <- 2
total_points <- 3

# Produces file but "File is not available on site"
create_certificate <-function(userFirstName,userLastName,final_score){
  template <-readr::read_file("certificate_template_pdf.Rmd")
  user_certificate <-template %>%
    str_replace("<<FIRSTNAME>>", paste0(userFirstName)) %>%
    str_replace("<<LASTNAME>>", paste(userLastName))
  # str_replace("<<SCORE>>", paste(final_score))
 
  out_filename <-paste(userLastName,userFirstName,"Certificate",sep="_")
  out_filename <-paste0(out_filename,'.pdf')
 
  write_file(user_certificate, "tmp.Rmd")
 
  user_pdf<-rmarkdown::render("tmp.Rmd", output_file = out_filename)
  file.remove("tmp.Rmd")
 
}

############## Application ########################

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("cerulean"),
                titlePanel("Color Exam"),
                shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
                mainPanel(width = "100%",
                          h5(htmlOutput("introduction")),
                          tags$head(tags$style("#introduction{color: black;}")),
                          uiOutput("name_fields"),
                          # h4("Question 1"),
                          # h5("Level: Knowledge"),
                          radioButtons("question_one", "What color is grass?",
                                       choices = c("green",
                                                   "yellow",
                                                   "blue",
                                                   "red"),
                                       selected = character(0),
                                       width = "100%"),
                          textOutput("question_one_fb"),
                          # h4("Question 2"),
                          # h5("Level: Comprehension"),
                          radioButtons("question_two", "Can apples be another color other than red?",
                                       choices = c("True", "False"),
                                       selected = character(0),
                                       width = "100%"),
                          textOutput("question_two_fb"),
                          actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
                          textOutput("score"),
                          textOutput("Score_Eval_msg"),
                          shinyjs::hidden(downloadButton("downloadCertificate", "Download Certificate"))
                ))

# Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$introduction <- renderUI({
    HTML("The following is a color exam of common objects.
    <p>The questions will be scored as follows:
    <p>level 1 = 1 point<br>level 2 = 2 points<br>level 3 = 3 points
    <p>Click <strong>Submit</strong> when you complete the exam.")
  })
 
  output$name_fields <- renderUI({
    fluidRow(
      column(6, textInput("first_name", "First Name:")),
      column(6, textInput("last_name", "Last Name:"))
    )
  })
 
  user_lastName <- reactiveVal()
  user_firstName <- reactiveVal()
 
  observeEvent(input$first_name, {
    user_firstName(input$first_name)
  })
 
  observeEvent(input$last_name, {
    user_lastName(input$last_name)
  })
 
  correct_question_one_answer <-"green"
  correct_question_two_answer <-"True"
 
  user_question_one_answer <- reactiveVal()
  user_question_two_answer <- reactiveVal()
 
  observeEvent(input$question_one, {
    user_question_one_answer(input$question_one)
  })
 
  observeEvent(input$question_two, {
    user_question_two_answer(input$question_two)
  })
 
 
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    question_one_answer <- user_question_one_answer()
    question_two_answer <- user_question_two_answer()
   
    if (is.null(question_one_answer)){
      question_one_feedback <-"Incorrect."
    } else if (question_one_answer!=correct_question_one_answer){
      question_one_feedback <-"Incorrect."
    } else {
      question_one_feedback <-"Correct!"
    }
   
   
    if (is.null(question_two_answer)){
      question_two_feedback <- "Incorrect."
    } else if(question_two_answer !=correct_question_two_answer) {
      question_two_feedback <- "Incorrect."
    } else {
      question_two_feedback <-"Correct!"
    }
   
    output$question_one_fb <- renderText({
      question_one_feedback
    })
   
    output$question_two_fb <- renderText({
      question_two_feedback
    })
   
    total_score <- ifelse(question_one_feedback == "Correct!", Knowledge, 0) +
      ifelse(question_two_feedback == "Correct!", Comprehension, 0)
   
    #Scoring
    scores <- reactiveValues(total = 0)
    scores$total <- total_score
    # Display total score
    output$score <- renderText({
      paste("Score: ", scores$total, "/",total_points)
    })
    #Score Evaluation
    final_score <-as.numeric(scores$total/total_points)
    # Score_Eval_msg <-ifelse(final_score >=0.80,"Congratulations! Please follow the instructions below to receive your certificate.","A passing score of 80% or higher is required. Please try again.")
    output$Score_Eval_msg <-renderText({Score_Eval_msg})
   
    if (final_score >= 0.80) {
      Score_Eval_msg <- paste0("Congratulations! Click the download button.")
      shinyjs::show("downloadCertificate")
    } else {
      Score_Eval_msg <- paste0("A passing score was not met, try again.")
      shinyjs::hide("downloadCertificate")
    }
   
    output$Score_Eval_msg <- renderText({
      Score_Eval_msg
    })
   
  }) # End of observeEvent input$submit
 
  # Error Produced: File wasn't available on site
  output$downloadCertificate <- downloadHandler(filename=function(){paste(user_lastName(), user_firstName(), "Certificate.pdf", sep = "_")},
                                                content = function(file) {
                                                  # create_certificate
                                                  create_certificate(user_firstName(),user_lastName())
                                                }  #end of content
                                               
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've tried pdf() and dev.off in the content part of the argument just to see if I could get the PDF to work but that didn't work either. I even moved the downloadHandler function and the creation function inside the observe event in the if statement but that didn't work either.